# What are some examples of proof by contrapositive?

Tags: proof-writing

Applying the [Modus Tollens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) argument to [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsLittleTheorem.html) really helped me to understand logical implication. I never knew that FLT was actually a *compositality* test.

Theorem (FLT): given integers $a>1$ and $n>1$, if $n$ is prime, then $a^n$ is congruent to $a\  (\bmod\  n)$.

By the contrapositive, if $a^n$ is **not** congruent to $a\  (\bmod\  n)$, then $n$ is **not** prime. Thus $n$ is composite.

> What are some other simple and instructive examples of proof by contrapositive?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/345978/12042) has a nice example; see especially the discussion in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/345991/12042). [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/288677/12042) and its answer are another, and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/88565/12042), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/200921/12042), and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/229105/12042) should also be of interest. These are just a few that I could easily find.

Comment: **Thanks** everyone for all the great examples. Now, I've got plenty to study. It sure would be interesting to compare samples from each [area of Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_areas_of_mathematics), a *"logic parallel"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to prove "If $p$ then $q$", and $p$ contains the phrase "$n$ is prime" you should use contrapositive or contradiction to work easily, the canonical example is the following:

Prove for $n>2$,

> If $n$ is prime then $n$ is odd.

Here $q$ is the phrase "$n$ is odd". Here $p$ is exactly the phrase "$n$ is prime" and is very difficult to work with it.
Because the fact that $n$ is prime means that it is not divisible by other number grater than $1$ and different for $n$, so you must to choose from these $n-2$ true sentences the only one that is useful which is "$n$ is not divisible by 2", but you would not know which is the right choice, unless you read $q$.

But proving contrapositive equivalent form is very easy, and you don't to do any choice.

> If $n$ is even then $n$ is not prime.

Which follows from the fact that every even number greater than $2$ is divisible by $2$, hence not prime.

So contrapositive (also contradiction) is used to avoid situations where you have a lot of information and very little of it is actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Richard Hammack's ["Book of Proof"](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/) for a detailed discussion of proof forms. There are several "proof technique" and such introductory courses (perhaps under discrete mathematics and similar) with lecture notes on the 'net.